# Using Visual Studio, what's an appropriate approach to test concurrency?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, concurrency

I need to simulate N users concurrently answering a question. Basically I just want to test if the code can handle concurrent updates to the same question object. What's an appropriate approach to test concurrency? Initially, I thought of doing a load test but thinking more about it, I don't think I can infer from the results accurately (for example, User1 and User2 answers a question at the same time. If User2 failed the first time, given the load test's iterations, it would probably pass in one of its succeeding tries.) Would a unit test be more appropriate?

Thank you for your help!!